# Generalized scalar product for matrices

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, linear-algebra

Let $X$ and $Y$ be matrices of a dimension $ m \times n $. I would like to keep $m$ and $n$ as a variable and define a scalar function $$ \operatorname{scalar}:  X ,  Y \to \mathbb R$$
$$
\operatorname{scalar}(X,Y ) = \sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{i=1}^m (x_{ij} - y_{ij})^2}
$$

This is how I orginally implemented it:

```
skalar[{{a_,b_},{c_,d_},{e_,f_}},{{g_,h_},{i_,j_},{k_,l_}}] =
 Sqrt[(a-g)^2 +(b-h)^2 +(c-i)^2 +(d-j)^2 +(e-k)^2 +(f-l)^2];
```

As you can see, it is bad.

Comment: `Norm[Array[A, {4, 3}] - Array[B, {4, 3}], "Frobenius"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The elementwise difference of 2 matrices x,y can simply be written as: x-y.
2. The elementwise square of a matrix x is simply x^2
3. To add all elements of a matrix, you may use "Flatten" and "Total"

   scalar[x_, y_] := Sqrt[Total[Flatten[(x - y)^2]]]

With this, e.g.:

```
x = {{1, 2}, {1, 2}};
y = {{2, 3}, {2, 3}};
scalar[x, y]

2
```

Answer (score 1):

Another method perhaps closer to the textbook could be: (Excuse the code formatting, it is deliberate)

```
Clear["Global`*"]
scalar[x_?MatrixQ, y_?MatrixQ] := Module[
  {m = First@Dimensions@x
   , n = Last@Dimensions@x
   },
  Sqrt[\!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(j = 1\), \(n\)]\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 1\), \(m\)]
\*SuperscriptBox[\((x[\([\)\(i, j\)\(]\)] - 
       y[\([\)\(i, j\)\(]\)])\), \(2\)]\)\)]
  ]
```

---

Screenshot:

[image]

**Usage:**

```
m = 2;
n = 3;
X = Array[x, {m, n}];
Y = Array[y, {m, n}];
scalar[X, Y]
```

$\sqrt{(x(1,1)-y(1,1))^2+(x(1,2)-y(1,2))^2+(x(1,3)-y(1,3))^2+(x(2,1)-y(2,1))^2+(x(2,2)-y(2,2))^2+(x(2,3)-y(2,3))^2}$

or

```
SeedRandom[1];
g = RandomReal[{-5, 5}, {4, 2}];
h = RandomReal[{-5, 5}, {4, 2}];
scalar[g, h]
```

> 13.3447